# Fail-safe injector for child modules. Optional bindings in google guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, optional-binding

I have a child module called ChildPlugin and I inject classes from main module as follows:

```
public class ChildPlugin {
    private ExampleClass demo;

    @Inject
    public void setDemo(ExampleClass demo) { 
        this.demo = demo;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know whether the main module binds `ExampleClass` and if it's not Guice throws an exception when creating the injector. What I want to do is to make Guice pass `null` or `Optional.empty` if ExampleClass is not binded.

I do not have access to the main module so I cannot change binder for `ExampleClass` to `OptionalBinder`, I tried `@Nullable` and `Optional<ExampleClass>` in `ChildPlugin.setDemo` method but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are 2 ways to do this.

Optional injection

Use the com.google.inject.Inject annotation. This one allows you to specify optional on the annotation. See this example:

```
public class GuiceInjectOptional extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        // method 1: 
        bind(B.class).in(Singleton.class);

    }

    public static class A {

        private String name;
        // non null constructor so that A can't be instantiated automatically by guice
        public A(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "I am: " + name;
        }
    }

    public static class B {

        @Inject(optional=true)
        A obj;

        void run() {
            System.out.println("Object is: " + obj);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceInjectOptional());
        injector.getInstance(B.class).run();;
    }

}
```

The annotation on class B indicates that A is optional. It does not get injected. Running the snippet prints:

```
Object is: null
```

Method 2 (which is the way you'd do it after guice 4+). You can specify optional bindings. These bindings even allow you to define default values if you like. You can then inject an optional value like in this snippet I wrote up:

```
public class GuiceInjectOptional extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // set up optional binding for A.
        OptionalBinder.newOptionalBinder(binder(), A.class);

        bind(B.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }

    public static class A {

        private String name;
        // non null constructor so that A can't be instantiated automatically by guice
        public A(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "I am: " + name;
        }
    }

    public static class B {

        @Inject
        Optional<A> obj;

        void run() {
            System.out.println("Object is present: " + obj.isPresent());
            System.out.println("Object is: " + obj);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceInjectOptional());
        injector.getInstance(B.class).run();;
    }

}
```

The Inject annotation is now non-optional, but guice is aware that class A may or may not have been bound. 
Running the snippet will print:

```
Object is present: false
Object is: Optional.empty
```

Finally, you can then just bind A normally and guice will inject it:

```
public class GuiceInjectOptional extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // set up optional binding for A.
        OptionalBinder.newOptionalBinder(binder(), A.class);

        bind(A.class).toInstance(new A("Pandaa!"));
        bind(B.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }

    public static class A {

        private String name;
        // non null constructor so that A can't be instantiated automatically by guice
        public A(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "I am: " + name;
        }
    }

    public static class B {

        @Inject
        Optional<A> obj;

        void run() {
            System.out.println("Object is present: " + obj.isPresent());
            System.out.println("Object is: " + obj);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceInjectOptional());
        injector.getInstance(B.class).run();;
    }

}
```

And the above will print:

```
Object is present: true
Object is: Optional[I am: Pandaa!]
```

And this is how you have fail safe optional bindings with guice :) I hope this helps.

Edit: I just saw the guice-3 tag, so you'll want to use the optional annotation method rather than the optional binder. With the optional annotation it will stay null instead of being an Optional value.

Artur

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm actually using guice 4, The problem with Optional is that the OptionalBinder must be set in parent module and I do not have access to the parent module, if I simply use Optional<A> in child injector and the parent module did not use OptionalBinder, Guice complains that the binding is not exists. However I didn't know about your first solution because I was using javax Injector. That solution worked for me, thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use an optinal binding yourself in your child module and just always have it there. In case the parent module adds a binding, your optional does nothing, otherwise it will use whatever is bound in your parent.